# Javascript speed improvements

Tags: javascript, performance, google-apps-script

Trying to speed up my google sheets script as it is taking for too long to load.

Basically I have a template sheet which is duplicated and certain columns hidden based on another tab.

The other tab simply lists the sheet name and has a "Y" in columns to indicate that that column needs to be visible on the newly created sheet.

The problem is that it is taking ages to go through the code and then to execute.
I am looking to speed up this process, I can't hard code it as the user might want to change things at any time.

Maybe an array to get the columns or something

I am new to javascript and struggling to make it more efficient

```
var lookUpValue = newSheetName;
var conVarCol = 13; //difference in columns on newssheet to where the column is located on shtPricing tab

for (i = 2; i < shtPricing.getLastRow() + 1; i++) // loop through all the cells in the row - Note the +1 on getastColumn is required or it misses the last column
{
  if (shtPricing.getRange(i, 3).getValue() == lookUpValue)
  //Finds a Match for the sheet name
  {
    var valueRow = i;

    for (p = 4; p < 23; p++) //Loop Through Columns in row the lookup row - starting at column 4 until the end
    {
      if (shtPricing.getRange(i, p).getValue() == 'Y') { //Then Yes Show Column
        newSheet.showColumns(p + conVarCol, 1)
      } else {
        newSheet.hideColumns(p + conVarCol, 1)
      }
    }
  }
} //End For
```

Comment: At the first glance, there is nothing wrong with your code. Potentially, some API calls are more expensive than expected. Can you add some profiling code to see the performance of each line?

Comment: This line: `for (i = 2; i < shtPricing.getLastRow() + 1; i++)` uses `getLastRow()` but your comment refers to `getLastColumn`  Is that a mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anyway to speed up the following code in google sheets script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51586034/anyway-to-speed-up-the-following-code-in-google-sheets-script)